# In Rcpp (and RcppArmadillo), how to check if a vec contains complex numbers?

Tags: c++, r, vector, rcpp, armadillo

In R, we can check whether a vector (e.g., `vec1=c(1+1i,2)`) contains complex numbers using is.complex (e.g., `is.complex(vec1)`). I wonder what the equivalent function is in RcppArmadillo?

And how to extract the real part of each element in the vector in RcppArmadillo, like `Re(vec1)` in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For extracting the real and imaginary parts, you can use the `arma::real()` and `arma::imag()` functions. Alternatively you can use the sugar function `Rcpp::Re()` and `Rcpp::Im()`:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec getRe(arma::cx_vec x) {
  return arma::real(x);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector getIm(Rcpp::ComplexVector x) {
  return Rcpp::Im(x);
}

/*** R
set.seed(42)
N <- 5
vec <- complex(5, rnorm(5), rnorm(5))

t(getRe(vec))
#>            [,1]        [,2]      [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
#> [1,] -0.9390771 -0.04167943 0.8294135 -0.4393582 -0.3140354
Re(vec)
#> [1] -0.93907708 -0.04167943  0.82941349 -0.43935820 -0.31403543

getIm(vec)
#> [1] -2.1290236  2.5069224 -1.1273128  0.1660827  0.5767232
Im(vec)
#> [1] -2.1290236  2.5069224 -1.1273128  0.1660827  0.5767232
*/
```

If you were to use `getRe(arma::vec x)` above, you would get:

```
Warning message:
In getRe(vec) : imaginary parts discarded in coercion
```

You just cannot put complex numbers in an object that is not meant to store them. This is a consequence of C++ being a strongly typed language. So there is no need for an analogue to `is.complex()`.

See the [Armadillo documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) for further reference.

Comment: The key really is in the penultimate paragraph: You don't as it is a stronly typed language.